# Python regex match n characters before the keyword

Tags: python, regex

I have a dataframe column looks like this

```
data
Membership 1 year
Individual - 10 years:
Membership 2019-2024
```

I want to extract the number before the keyword 'year'.
I'd like to get output:

```
data                      contract_years
Membership 1 year         1
Individual - 10 years:    10
Membership 2019-2024
```

I tried
`\d{2}+(?=year)` which is obviously wrong. Any suggestion will be really helpful, thanks.

Comment: I think you mean `\d{2}\syears`. `\s` means whitespace, `+` is a quantifier. You'll also need to use a capture group around the number so you can extract it.

Comment: this will do it `(\d+) year`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df['contract_years'] = df['data'].str.extract('(\d+) year')`

Answer (score -1):

```
`(\d+)[ ]*[yY][eE][aA][rR][sS]?`
```

Try this where I use `\d+` to get the numbers, and `[ ]*[yY][eE][aA][rR][sS]?` to know if there is a year or years ahead, regardless if it is in uppercase or lowercase and how many spaces there are before the word.